# Ubuntu startup stuck on black screen with /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, system-installation

so I just bought a new laptop and used a bootable usb to install ubuntu 18.04 os on it. I was able to go through the install (although the touchscreen and touchpad didnt work I was able to use the keyboard to go through) and this seemed to work fine. After installing and plling out bootable usb and restarting, the message `/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 137978/31227904 files, 3766150/124895488 blocks` and it gets stuck there. I looked around and couldnt find anything that worked. The only thing I believe I have done to change my computers settings is switching from RAID SATA to AHCI SATA, but this didnt work I also tried reinstalling ubuntu after this switch but now ubuntu install gets stuck on the startup with the logo and dots underneath it. I also used a command (i dont remember it exactly, it was like sudo apt (something) nvidia*) to remove nvidia drivers, this also did not work.

Could anyone give me some advice, I would be very happy if I could get my new laptop working again.

### Computer Specs

`Dell Inspiron 17 7000 Series 2-in-1`

`Model: 7791`

`Display: 17.3" FHD Touch Display with Webcam`

`Processor: Intel Core i7-10510U`

`16GB Memory`

`Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce MX250 2GB`

UPDATE : Hey, sorry for not replying to people.. Update for the record and other people that may see this as reference in the future, I never fully got this to work. I was able to get the computer to boot ubuntu doing what some of the comments below said however the touchpad was not working and I was kinda tired of working on it, so I ended up switching back to windows and returning the laptop to swap for a new Samsung Notebook 9 2-in-1, which honestly is all around a nicer laptop and the swap to ubuntu was super easy. After installing everything worked out of the box, even the 3d touch pen stylist and touchscreen! Thanks guys!

Comment: Could you try adding nouveau.modeset=0 on the kernel parameter?

Comment: this totally worked @jrandiny however touchscreen and touchpad still do not work. after using less on /proc/bus/input/devices and looking through the list I do not see any input devices for either

Comment: Please try with the newest possible Ubuntu iso file, [19.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/eoan/) or even the developing version [Focal Fossa](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/408/builds/202857/downloads) (to become 20.04 LTS in April 2020). With a new version you get a new linux kernel and with a new linux kernel you get new hardware drivers, and this may help with your new computer.

Comment: Are you trying to use LightDM? I tried to use LightDM and it was causing issues, and when I switched to GDM3 they all went away. Just something to try (I can't make a comment).

Answer (score 1):

I have a dell Inspiron 15 7000 2 in 1
added modeprobe.blacklist=intel_lpss_pci to grub line
Manage to install but no touchpad/touchscreen.
not showing up in /proc/bus/input/devices either

Comment: Please tell us with more details what you have tried, what works and what does not work: The version/flavour of Ubuntu, what drivers and program packages that are installed/used and what you have tweaked. The information about the blacklisting is useful for us [other users], but please tell us more :-)

Comment: I tried with 19.10 also with no resolve. Also just tried building linux kernel from source. Didn't work ( 5.4 )

Comment: I have good experience with older Dell computers including Precision and Latitude with generation 4 intel i7 and i5 CPUs. It makes me sad to read, that Ubuntu has problems with this new model, and I hope that someone can chip in with a solution.

Comment: I believe the solution lays here. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_2-in-1_(7390)
"
To fix the intel_lpss_module the patch from this paste must be applied to the kernel.

https://pastebin.com/sqPv8ShP " Probably the same chipset.

Comment: Great news :-) I suggest that you update your answer with the content of your comments.